# Qt - Info not loading in ListView

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QListView which uses a model to load information to it. Bug when I insert new Rows into the model, it doesn't show up in the QListView. These are the codes I used:

in header:

```
bugModel = new QStandardItemModel();
ui->bugList->setModel(bugModel);
```

in cpp (when button pressed):

```
bugModel->insertRows(bugModel->rowCount(), 1);
bugModel->setData(bugModel->index(bugModel->rowCount()-1,0), "Test");
```

What could be the problem?

P.S The function does get called when the button is pressed as I checked it using qDebug().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add column?
If not - add line `bugModel->insertColumn(0);` in header.

Comment: Oops..Silly little mistake. Thanks, didn't come to my mind :)